# Where to put code in the Flutter app to execute once by session and after user log in?

Tags: flutter, dart, authentication

So I have the Flutter app, and the user must log in if the user wants to use our app. And I have some functions that need to be triggered once by session and if a user is logged in. So my question is where to put this piece of code, inside the main function or somewhere else, and what will happen if the user put the app in the background mode?

Answer (score 0):

First off, you have two options for where to put that code. You can either drop it inside the `main()` function itself or add it in some widget that is fired upon login, depending on how your app is set up and what you need.

**Inside the `main()` function**:
If you decide to pop the code right into the `main()` function, it'll fire up as soon as the app starts. The only catch is that it'll run every time the app is launched, not just once per session. So, if you're after that one-time magic, this might not be your best bet.

**Inside some widget**:
The second option gives you more control. You can tuck the code into a relevant spot, like inside a specific widget or a state management class. For example, you could trigger it right after the user logs in on the `LoginScreen`, or even within a fancy `StateNotifier` or `Bloc class` managing the user authentication state.

Also, when your app goes into the background, it's in the `AppLifecycleState.paused` state. But when it comes back to life and enters the foreground, it switches to the `AppLifecycleState.resumed` state.

And the cherry on top, you can actually listen to these `lifecycle events`. So when your app resumes, you can do some nifty stuff, like re-authenticating the user without them even knowing!

Comment: So, to create one Bloc and in that bloc to listen AppLifecycleState, and to create a logic there if AppLifecyleState.resumes and if user is logged in trigger the function? 

So you mean this flow be correct?

Comment: And one more thing, what will be happen if that widget is not the first one that will open after app is in the background mode?

Comment: You got it! That's exactly the right flow!

Create a Bloc (or a StateNotifier or any state management solution you prefer) and make it listen to the `AppLifecycleState` changes. When the app goes into the background (in the `paused` state) and comes back to the foreground (in the `resumed` state), your Bloc will be `notified`.

In that Bloc, you can add the logic to check if the user is logged in. If the user is indeed logged in, go ahead and trigger that function you want to run once per session.